# Is there a tool for validating /etc/network/interfaces files?

Tags: networking, server, configuration

I always like to test new config files before deploying them--with tools like `apachectl configtest` and `named-checkconf`.

It's rare that mistakes crop up, but catching them before deployment eliminates any impact. The one that has bit me in the backside several times is `/etc/network/interfaces`; I can't seem to find a tool to test it, and restarting the network on a remote machine only to discover it's no longer reachable is quite annoying--especially when we use a lot of bonding and bridging.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To expand upon [@jdthood's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/228614/17164)...

If the interface is already up, you can still use this method to validate the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. For example, assuming you have an error, you may see something like this:

```
$ sudo ifup --no-act eth0
/etc/network/interfaces:11: unknown method
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

Apparently there's an error on line 11. Great. Thank heavens I didn't bounce the networking only to lose SSH access!

If all is fine, you will see:

```
$ sudo ifup --no-act eth0
ifup: interface eth0 already configured
```

Answer (score 10):

The following may do part of what you want.

```
ifup --no-act eth0
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have a eth0 this will not work, eg:

```
Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0.
```

But if you do like this:

```
ifup -a --no-act ; echo "status: $?"
```

With ok config:

```
ifup -a --no-act ; echo "status: $?"
run-parts  /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts  /etc/network/if-up.d
status: 0
```

With non-ok config:

```
ifup -a --no-act ; echo "status: $?"
/etc/network/interfaces:12: option with empty value
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
status: 1
```